# Testes unitários de atributos de modelo em aplicação spring boot

Tags: java, spring, testes-de-unidade, spring-boot

Boa tarde

Nao tenho muita experiência com testes unitários. Estou testando controllers em uma aplicação spring boot, mas cometi algum erro no teste de atributos do modelo, que aparentemente nem é reconhecido no teste. Abaixo o stack e minhas classes.Desde já obrigado pela ajuda!

Failure trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'restaurants'
Expected: a collection with size <2>
     but: collection size was <0>
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ModelResultMatchers$1.match(ModelResultMatchers.java:58)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
    at com.matmr.restaurantpoll.controller.RestaurantControllerTest.should_search(RestaurantControllerTest.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

RestaurantControlerTest.class

```
package com.matmr.restaurantpoll.controller;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasProperty;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.model;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.view;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import com.matmr.restaurantpoll.model.Category;
import com.matmr.restaurantpoll.model.Restaurant;
import com.matmr.restaurantpoll.model.filter.RestaurantFilter;
import com.matmr.restaurantpoll.service.RestaurantService;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public class RestaurantControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private RestaurantService restaurantService;

    @InjectMocks
    private RestaurantController restaurantController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(restaurantController).setRemoveSemicolonContent(false).build();

    }

    @Test
    public void should_search() throws Exception {

        RestaurantFilter filter = new RestaurantFilter();
        filter.setName(null);

        Restaurant first = new RestaurantBuilder()
                .id(1L)
                .name("Abra")
                .description("lots of food")
                .category(Category.ITALIAN).build();

        Restaurant second = new RestaurantBuilder()
                .id(2L)
                .name("Kadabra")
                .description("food for days")
                .category(Category.PIZZA).build();

        when(restaurantService.findByNameIgnoreCaseContaining(filter)).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(first, second));

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/restaurants"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("restaurantList"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("restaurants", hasSize(2)))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("restaurants",
                    hasItem(allOf(
                            hasProperty("id", is(1L)),
                            hasProperty("name", is("Abra")),
                            hasProperty("description", is("lots of food"))
                            ))))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("restaurants",
                    hasItem(allOf(
                            hasProperty("id", is(2L)),
                            hasProperty("name", is("Kadabra")),
                            hasProperty("description", is("food for days"))
                            ))));

        verify(restaurantService, times(1)).findByNameIgnoreCaseContaining(filter);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(restaurantService);

    }

}
```

RestaurantController.class

```
package com.matmr.restaurantpoll.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.matmr.restaurantpoll.model.Restaurant;
import com.matmr.restaurantpoll.model.filter.RestaurantFilter;
import com.matmr.restaurantpoll.service.RestaurantService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/restaurants")
public class RestaurantController {

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantService restaurantService;

    @RequestMapping
    public ModelAndView pesquisar(@ModelAttribute("filtro") RestaurantFilter filter) {

        List<Restaurant> filterRestaurants = restaurantService.findByNameIgnoreCaseContaining(filter);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("restaurantList");
        mv.addObject("restaurants", filterRestaurants);

        return mv;
    }

}
```

restaurantList.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorator="layout">
<head>
<title>Pesquisa de Restaurantes</title>
</head>

<section layout:fragment="conteudo">

    <div layout:include="MensagemGeral"></div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <h1 class="panel-title liberty-title-panel">Pesquisa de
                    Restaurantes</h1>
                <a class="btn btn-link liberty-link-panel"
                    th:href="@{/titulos/novo}">Cadastrar Novo Restaurante</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">



            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center col-md-1">#</th>
                            <th class="text-left col-md-2">Nome</th>
                            <th class="text-left col-md-3">Descrição</th>
                            <th class="text-left col-md-2">Categoria</th>
                            <th class="col-md-1"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr th:each="restaurant : ${restaurants}">

                            <td class="text-center" th:text="${restaurant.id}"></td>

                            <td class="text-center" th:text="${restaurant.name}"></td>

                            <td th:text="${restaurant.description}"></td>

                            <td th:text="${restaurant.category.description}"></td>

                            <td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-link btn-xs"
                                th:href="@{/restaurants/{id}(id=${restaurant.id})}"
                                title="Editar" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top"> <span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                            </a> <a class="btn btn-link btn-xs" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#confirmRemove"
                                th:attr="data-id=${restaurant.id}, data-name=${restaurant.name}"
                                title="Excluir" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top"> <span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                            </a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6" th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(restaurants)}">Nenhum
                                restaurante foi encontrado!</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div layout:include="confirmRemove"></div>

    </div>
</section>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a asserção do mock está errada. Tente usar assim:

`when(restaurantService.findByNameIgnoreCaseContaining(eq(filter))).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(first, second));`

ou então, de modo mais genérico, um retorno por base do tipo da classe

`when(restaurantService.findByNameIgnoreCaseContaining(isA(filter.getClass()))).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(first, second));`

A propósito, esse *eq* e *isA* são métodos estáticos de **org.mockito.Matchers**